# joomla redirects to website index after saving article

Tags: joomla

A while ago i updated the Joomla version on my website to 3.3.6 everything went well my website is running as it should.

while i was editing one of the articles i tried clicking save&close it will not save the article instead it redirects to the front end index page.

I am expecting the redirect to go back to administrators index page after saving the article.

I tried erasing all cookies on my browser and even used another browser to test if the problem is with my google chrome.

Any help will be a blessing, Thank you.

Below is the system info that might help.

```
PHP Built On    Linux lax03.web.com.ph 2.6.32-531.23.3.lve1.2.66.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 12 10:57:40 EDT 2014 x86_64
Database Version    5.5.40-cll
Database Collation  latin1_swedish_ci
PHP Version 5.4.36
Web Server  Apache
WebServer to PHP Interface  cgi-fcgi
Joomla! Version Joomla! 3.3.6 Stable [ Ember ] 01-October-2014 02:00 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version    Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my joomla 2.5.28 and after struggling a little bit i figured out where it was coming from.
In fact, I copied my site from my online hosting server to a local server: I noticed that it was 10 times faster and i could save, save & close without any redirects. I concluded that it is coming from the server so I called my hosting company and they told me that they enabled a security feature for the accounts and one client of them has complained already and that they disabled the feature and the client's site came back to normal.

**What is the name of that feature?**  *[ModSecurity](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Apache+Module:+ModSecurity)*

"ModSecurity" was enabled for my account and that gave me a headache for a few weeks.
Where to find "ModSecurity"?
Login to your Cpanel

- Look for security menu
- Look for "Modsecurity"
- Click it and disable it.

Voilà!

That worked for me.

Comment: This was exactly my case for my Joomla 3.5.1 installation. ModSecurity was enabled. After disabling Saving of entries was possible again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour is indeed to take you back to the article management page.

I have seen this happen because of two reasons:
1) a third party plugin could be causing the problem
2) you are using an old 2.5 template for administrator, try using Isis.

Take a look at your php / apache error logs there may be a clue there if the issue lies with a plugin.

-- Update after comments --

3) If the above fails, try renaming the plugins/system folder to plugins/systemX, if the site loads you know the issue is in the systems plugins, and you can go inside and rename non-Joomla plugins in turns to quickly see which is causing the issue; if the site doesn't load, the issue is not in the system plugins, you can try other types except for user and authentication, which you need to login.

Comment: i see no errors on the log uninstalled newly installed plugins but the behavior is the same

Answer (score 0):

Some times before I encounter with similar issue. After several research I resolve the issue by correcting joomla **tmp** and **log** path. I think you should try this.